# What does 'master' mean in command "git branch --merged master"?

Tags: git, version-control, branch

From syntax of git branch at http://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch, the last optional parameters are either "commit" or "pattern".

```
git branch [--color[=<when>] | --no-color] [-r | -a] 
[--list] [-v [--abbrev=<length> | --no-abbrev]]
[--column[=<options>] | --no-column]
[(--merged | --no-merged | --contains) [<commit>]] [<pattern>...]
```

So in the command "git branch --merged master", is "master" considered the commit name or pattern? (I'm guessing 'master' in this command is referring to local branch master.)

What is the difference between "git branch --merged master" vs. "git branch --merged develop"? Will the output of the command vary if the checked out branch is master vs. develop?

I saw this post, but quite didn't understand what the "master" parameter value maps to in the command syntax. 
[Git: How to find all branches that were never merged back into master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19651040/git-how-to-find-all-branches-that-were-never-merged-back-into-master/19651058#19651058)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git branch --merged` will show you all branches which have been merged into the commit you give on the command line. If you specify `master`, that will be the tip (last) commit on your branch master. Same goes for `develop`.

It doesn't matter which branch you have currently checked out, unless you don't specify a commit (i.e. only `git branch --merged`). Then the currently checked out `HEAD` will be used.

Comment: thanks @knittl. From the documentation it wasn't clear that branchname can also be specified as the parameter.