# Git Command for a custom purpose

Tags: git, github, version-control, merge, git-branch

There are a lot of `feature / hotfix` Git branches I created from `dev` branch and developed things and merged back to `dev` branch. But, meanwhile I forgot to delete local `feature / hotfix` branches after merging with the development `dev` branch. I would be happy to know if there is a command which would list all the branch names that had been checked out from `dev` branch initially and merged to `dev` branch after its completion. Also, if possible fetch all the branches which are deleted remotely but not locally. Currently I am standing at `dev` branch.

I have used

> git log dev --pretty=oneline --graph

command to see all merge and pull requests created from `dev` branch. But then I needed to inspect to find out the branch names. If there is a specific command to output the branch names, it would have been better. Thank you for any help :)

Comment: This may be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127328/how-can-i-delete-all-git-branches-which-have-been-merged

Answer (score 1):

You can find all branches that are fully merged with the `dev` branch (including `dev` itself) using

```
git branch --merged dev
```

Comment: Hah, answered simultaneously )

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19651040/git-how-to-find-all-branches-that-were-never-merged-back-into-master